# Javax.mail.* Package does not exist - Why?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Im using a class called emailer to send an email from a java application,
I am using **netbeans 6.9.1** and I am using J2SE, I downloaded the javamail api and added the jar to the `classpath` and also put it in the `src` for netbeans.

Netbeans is throwing up an error saying `Package javax.mail does not exist` and I dont know why? As I feel I have done everything correct, here is the code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

/**
* Simple demonstration of using the javax.mail API.
*
* Run from the command line. Please edit the implementation
* to use correct email addresses and host name.
*/
public final class Emailer {

  public static void main( String... aArguments ){
    Emailer emailer = new Emailer();
        try {

            emailer.sendEmail("fromblah@blah.com", "toblah@blah.com", "Testing 1-2-3", "blah blah blah");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Emailer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
   }


  public void sendEmail(String aFromEmailAddr, String aToEmailAddr,
    String aSubject, String aBody) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
      Class.forName("javax.mail");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance( fMailServerConfig, null );
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage( session );
    try {

      message.addRecipient(
        Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(aToEmailAddr)
      );
      message.setSubject( aSubject );
      message.setText( aBody );
      Transport.send( message );
    }
    catch (MessagingException ex){
      System.err.println("Cannot send email. " + ex);
    }
  }


  public static void refreshConfig() {
    fMailServerConfig.clear();
    fetchConfig();
  }



  private static Properties fMailServerConfig = new Properties();

  static {
    fetchConfig();
  }


  private static void fetchConfig() {
    InputStream input = null;
    try {

      input = new FileInputStream( "C:\\Temp\\MyMailServer.txt" );
      fMailServerConfig.load( input );
    }
    catch ( IOException ex ){
      System.err.println("Cannot open and load mail server properties file.");
    }
    finally {
      try {
        if ( input != null ) input.close();
      }
      catch ( IOException ex ){
        System.err.println( "Cannot close mail server properties file." );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It sounds like the project configuration in netbeans still isn't set up correctly.

Comment: You need to right click on the project name in the project tab the go to Properties-> Libraries -> Press Add Jar/Folder... Browse and select your jar...and click OK...and build and re-run

Comment: or, alternatively, you can go to properties -> compiling and select the "compile on save" option, which will clean and rebuild automatically when you change anything after a few seconds.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question directly, it's much easier if you use a build system like Gradle or Maven. These will automatically download dependencies into your classpath, and Netbeans understands them.

Answer (score 3):

Add javax.mail.jar and activation.jar to
Go to your project -> Build path -> Configure build path -> Java build path -> libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to right click on the project name in the project tab the go to

> Properties-> Libraries -> Press Add
>   Jar/Folder

... Browse and select your jar...and click OK...and

> Clean and Build and re-run

Comment: @ThreaT If you will look closely at the **QUESTION** the OP has mentioned "_I downloaded the javamail api and added the jar_" So its understood which jar this answer is referring to....And just in case you don't know this applies to any jar file you add to the project

Comment: Download the jar you need to add from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html